# SharePoint Article Headline Character Cutoff

Tags: sharepoint

When a news article is created on SharePoint, the headline when on the page of the article appears to cut off at a certain character/word and adds an ellipsis at the end. If there any way you can extend this character length? Or would I have to create a new custom page?

Thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZg3Y.png

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use a Content By Query Webpart (CQWP) to display them. You can customize the XSL as you need. check this out : http://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/display-news-pages-with-cqwp-%E2%80%93-part-i/